# Changing parameters based on qt combo box

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

I have a combo box called x_axis_unit in qt with two options; metres and ms. When I change the options, the combo box doesn't take note of the change and stays stuck on metres after I changed the option to ms once I exit the gui. I typed in

```
 ui->plot_type->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

but that doesn't set it. So what argument is needed to set the current index to its current value? Also based on the current option I'd like to run a loop that changes another parameter. So if the current text in the combo box is metres then I set a variable called axis to 0 and if it is in ms then I set the variable to 1

// Combo box code

```
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->x_axis_unit->addItem("metres");
ui->x_axis_unit->addItem("ms");
```

So how can I set the combo box to ms, it is always on metres.

Comment: Which version of `Qt` are you using? Here I've got 4.8 and I can't find the `setCurrentText` method. But you can use `setCurrentIndex` to specify an item in the combo.

Comment: 5.3, if I  use that method and change the combo box item will it stay set?

Comment: `will it stay set` I don't get this... But using `setCurrentIndex` should change the `selected` item in the combo. For example, if you have 2 items inserted and call `setCurrentIndex(1)`, the combo will have selected the second item (remember, 0-based indices)

Comment: As for why `setCurrentText` doesn't work, I can only speculate. Maybe you are calling it with a string that doesn't match an item (e. g: combo has an item called `my cat` and you call `setCurrentText("mycat")`, or the combo isn't editable or you haven't inserted any items yet.

Comment: I don't want to set it manually I want the combo box's current index to remain set once changed. Eg if there are 3 options and I select the second one I would like that to remain as the current index of the box until changed again.

Comment: That's the usual logic with the combo. For what I read in your description, you're setting a variable and you want the combo to change its selection acording to that. Am I right?

Comment: Yes that's one issue, but first I'd like the combo box to be set to whatever item I pick from the two items/options I added. It doesn't change currently it stays on the first item

Comment: That's strange. Please, post the code for the combo box creation and any slots attached to it.

Comment: I've updated the question, I have a short meeting to attend so I I'll be away for half an hour, but I still need some help with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69204/discussion-between-adri-c-s-and-duanne).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an enum to store the index for the combo box.

If the enum has class scope you can then change the combo box from any function in the class with "comboBox.setCurrentIndex(enum entry)" like this:

```
enum comboBoxSelection
{
    eMetres = 0,
    eMS
};

x_axis_unit = new QComboBox(parent);

x_axis_unit->insertItem(eMetres, "Metres");
x_axis_unit->insertItem(eMS, "ms");

x_axis_unit->setCurrentIndex(eMS);
```